# Телеграм интерпретирует даты как ссылки. Как отучить?

Tags: дата, telegram-bot, markdown

При выводе ботом в чат (с включенным маркдаун), некоторые даты почему-то интерпретируются телеграмом как ссылки (подчеркиваются). Проблема в том, что после этой ссылки, вывод последующих сообщений в чат от бота прекращается.
Пример: из бота выводится серия из 10 сообщений вида "Фамилия - дата (цифра)". В одном из сообщений (допустим, в 5-м) дата выводится как ссылка и все последующие сообщения (от 6-го и далее) в чат не попадают. Если убрать дату из вывода или изменить её формат (что не всегда приемлемо) проблема пропадает, выводятся все сообщения. В чем дело, как предотвратить?

Замечено, например, на "25.06.2018", "12.08.2018" и др.

Comment: Наверное, тем что похоже на url. Типо ru.stackoverflow.com. Попробуйте формат поменять на dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: 1. замена формата в котором вместо точек - слешы, пробелы - не помогает. сейчас использую формат с текстовым написанием месяцев, но это не выход. 
2. воспринимает не как url, а как номер телефона, предлагает по тапу набрать.

Comment: Интересно, а если номер даты вывести в эмоджи-смайлах (там ведь цифры тоже есть)? :D

Comment: покажите код который формирует этот текст

Comment: @Anatol
`(chatId, $"▪ *{p.Name}*\n{p.HolidayType} - {p.Start.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")} ({p.Len} дн.)")` - вариант, который иногда дает ошибочные ссылки.
`(chatId, $"▪ *{p.Name}*\n{p.Start.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", ci)} ({p.Len} дн.)")` - переделанный вариант, работает всегда.

Comment: parse_mode при этом какой задаётся? именно markdown?

Comment: а второй случай - это с явным указанием локали?

Comment: @Anatol
1) parseMode, как и указано в исходном вопросе - ParseMode.Markdown. для него и звездочки в строке.
2) да. явно указан CultureInfo для вывода месяца на русском. в выводе с ошибками - включение CultureInfo на результат никак не влияло